# T-SQL - Inserting 3.5M rows increases the transaction log size to max

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, bulkinsert, open-json

Following is the query I am using to parse 3.5M rows of JSON data and insert it into another table.

```
DECLARE @id_control bigint
    DECLARE @batchSize bigint
    DECLARE @results nvarchar(256)
    DECLARE @NextFetchValue bigint

    SET @results = 1
    SET @batchSize = 20000
    SET @id_control = 0
    

    WHILE (@results > 0)
    BEGIN
        set @NextFetchValue = null
        set @NextFetchValue = cast(@id_control as bigint)+ cast( @batchSize as bigint)
         
     
            set @InsertTableQuery = 'insert into '+@Schemaname+'.'+@Tablename+' (ColId, '+replace(@SQL,'nvarchar(max)','')+')
            select top '+cast(@batchSize as nvarchar(256))+' a.RN, qse.* from(select qs.Query, QS.QId    as RN from tools.QueryStore qs with(nolock)) a                     
                    cross apply openjson(a.Query) 
                    with
                        (
                            '+@SQL+'
                        )qse 
                    where RN > '+cast(@id_control as nvarchar(256))+' and RN <= '+cast(@NextFetchValue as nvarchar(256))

            exec sp_executesql  @InsertTableQuery


           
           SET @results = @@ROWCOUNT
           
     

       -- next batch
       SET @id_control = @id_control + @batchSize
    END
```

Here is the query output

```
insert into dbo.Stgtable (ColId, Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , Col4 , Col5 , Col6 , Col7 , Col8 , Col9 , Col10 , Col11 , Col12 , Col14 , Col15 , Col16 , Col17 , Col21 , Col22 , Col23 , Col24 , Col27 , Col28 , Col29 , Col30 , Col31 , Col32 , Col33 , Col34 , Col35 , Col36 )
            select top 20000 a.RN, qse.* from(select qs.Query, QS.QId    as RN from tools.QueryStore qs with(nolock)) a                     
                    cross apply openjson(a.Query) 
                    with
                        (
                            Col1 nvarchar(max), Col2 nvarchar(max), Col3 nvarchar(max), Col4 nvarchar(max), Col5 nvarchar(max), Col6 nvarchar(max), Col7 nvarchar(max), Col8 nvarchar(max), Col9 nvarchar(max), Col10 nvarchar(max), Col11 nvarchar(max), Col12 nvarchar(max), Col14 nvarchar(max), Col15 nvarchar(max), Col16 nvarchar(max), Col17 nvarchar(max), Col21 nvarchar(max), Col22 nvarchar(max), Col23 nvarchar(max), Col24 nvarchar(max), Col27 nvarchar(max), Col28 nvarchar(max), Col29 nvarchar(max), Col30 nvarchar(max), Col31 nvarchar(max), Col32 nvarchar(max), Col33 nvarchar(max), Col34 nvarchar(max), Col35 nvarchar(max), Col36 nvarchar(max)
                        )qse 
                    where RN > 0 and RN <= 20000
```

During the execution of the query in batches - my transaction log size increases drastically.

How to insert millions of records quickly without increasing the transaction log?

Comment: *insert millions of records quickly* - that alone is quite a challenge .... *without increasing the transaction log* - and that's going to make it near impossible .....

Comment: All your columns are defined as nvarchar(max). This is VERY inefficient. You should choose more appropriate data types, like int, date, etc. This will help to keep the size of the transaction log down.

Comment: You could look at changing the Recovery Model of the database from FULL to BULK LOGGED. This will reduce the amount of transaction log created. However, this does mean you do not have point-in-time recovery for the duration the database is in BULK LOGGED model.